# a4j:commandButton gives NullPointerException with t:inputFileUpload

Tags: file-upload, jsf-2, ajax4jsf, tomahawk

Why is it that for the below code, when I use `t:commandButton` it works fine and in case of `a4j:commandButton` it gives `NullPointerException` on `uploadedFile.getInputStream()` ?

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <t:inputFileUpload value="#{fileUploadController.uploadedFile}"/>
    <t:commandButton action="#{fileUploadController.insertFile}"/>      
</h:form>
```

Comment: Not a duplicate, but it might be related to subject of the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10754300/tinputfileupload-not-uploading-the-file) somehow.

Comment: @Gamb I've already checked all the question on SO related to `fileUpload`, even the question you've mentioned however I couldn't found my answer. So had to ask this !

Comment: Answer is same as this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10754300/tinputfileupload-not-uploading-the-file

Comment: @GuilhermeLemes Thanks for your response, I was able to figure out the cause then only. I just got confused due to the richfaces showcase.