# Best practice for multiple (single) file uploads in JSF 2.2

Tags: ajax, jsf, file-upload, primefaces

Our JSF 2.2 web application may have the situation, that users have to fill in a formular where they have to upload multiple files.

#### Example

```
First Name: [ John        ]
Last Name:  [ Doe         ]
Photo:      [ choose File ] (no file chosen)
Passport:   [ choose File ] (no file chosen)
```

I know that there is multiple upload forms like [Primefaces](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/multiple.xhtml) but this doesn't fit to my requirement, since I want to know which file is either the photo or passport, and I need to validate the input, because the files are mandatory.

---

#### Option 1: Multiple single file uploads

The first option would be like in the example above. Just use multiple single `<h:inputFile>` tags.

Pros:

- users select files when they are asked for
- users know this kind of file uploads

Cons:

- since there are more `<h:inputFile>` tags, every file upload will be processed during the form submit: so we might have to limit filesizes so that users won't run into problems
- I did not try this: is it even possible to use multiple single file uploads in the same `<h:form>`?

---

#### Option 2: Upload in popup + callback

I have seen this sometimes and wondered why it was implemented that way. When you have to upload a file it opens a popup with a file upload. After the upload, the popup is closed and the form has selected the uploaded file.

Are there any hints/tutorials for this technique? Especially the between-window-communication is unclear for me.

Pros:

- nearly the same as the standard way

Cons:

- problems with popup-blockers
- for this approach, fallback mechanics have to be implemented: what if the user cancels the form? when are uploaded files deleted, so that there are no garbage files?

---

#### Option 3: Upload in modal dialog + callback

To eliminate the popup blocker problem we could use a modal dialog for an upload. So we choose to upload a file, a new modal `<p:dialog modal="true"/>` opens and there inside the `<h:inputFile>` handles your upload.

I did try this and found out that AJAX uploads are not possible with `<h:inputFile>` or `<p:inputFile mode="simple">` (can't find the source of BalusC's comment, but there is a [similar one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10756326/1213544)). My whole site got rerendered and my formular input was lost.

Pros:

- nearly the same as the standard way
- no problems with popup blockers

Cons:

- even possible?

---

#### Option 4: "Upload Manager"

My last idea was to provide an upload manager. This is a view where users can see their uploaded files in a list/table and add files with a *single* `<h:inputFile>`, add descriptions, and so on. So the files are already in the system and get deleted after (say) 72 hours if they are not referenced.

Users then click on a link when they have to input a file, and choose the corresponding file from a list/table in a modal dialog. Therefore users have to upload their files first, before even filling a form, which is quite a pain, so it would be nice if they could also upload files in the modal dialog. (this would look like a view, where they have a single `<h:inputFile>` and a list of their already uploaded files). But there we have the same AJAX problem like in Option 3...

The only way I see to get around this, is to write something at the beginning of a form like:

```
For this form you need the following files in your upload manager:
 - Photo
 - Passport
```

Pros:

- technically: good because it's always only one file in a submit (AJAX?)
- no specific fallback mechanisms (except a 72hrs cronjob deleting unused files)
- users can upload multiple files for the (say) next 20 forms - this is good in our web application

Cons:

- users are not used to this technique
- even possible?

---

Do you have any other ideas to handle with this situation? I can't be the only one with this.
Or are multiple file uploads like Primefaces good to configure for validations?

I hope you can help me out with this brainstorming

Comment: I would go with option 1. Easy to implement, easy to use & understand for the users. You will just need two `<p:fileUpload>`, and two `UploadedFile` objects in the backing bean. But as always, it really depends on the current requirements, and it can later change, so YOU have to take everything into account.

Comment: Thank you for clarification that multiple single inputs are possible. I was unsure about that. The only drawback i see is the duration of requests if there is more than one file. But I will consider that...