# <t:inputFileUpload> not working anymore after migration JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.2

Tags: jsf, file-upload, servlet-filters, jsf-2.2, tomahawk

I am upgrading my application from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.2 and using Tomahawk 1.1.14 version.

After upgrading, `<t:inputFileUpload>` tag has stopped working and value of the component is not bound to backingbean property any more.

`web.xml`

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.LIBRARIES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/facelets/tags/tomahawk.taglib.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

However, I saw on myfaces site that the above parameter is deprecated. Is there any other way to include tag libraries or is it not even required with JSF 2.2?

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>uploadMaxFileSize</param-name>
        <param-value>50m</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>uploadThresholdSize</param-name>
        <param-value>1024k</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/myFacesExtensionResource/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Before this filter, I do have another filter in my web.xml and it is

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>AjaxAnywhere</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.ajaxanywhere.AAFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>preSendHandlerClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.ajaxanywhere.jsf.MyFacesClientStateSavingPreSendHandler</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AjaxAnywhere</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Can anyone please help me if I need to do any more configuration changes for Tomahawk to work with JSF 2.2?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since JSF 2.2, the `FacesServlet` will automatically parse `multipart/form-data` requests all by itself with help of new Servlet 3.0 [`@MultiartConfig`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/annotation/MultipartConfig.html) annotation. Also, since JSF 2.2 there is (finally!) a standard file upload component, the [`<h:inputFile>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/h/inputFile.html).

The MyFaces extensions filter and Tomahawk file upload component is basically incompatible with JSF 2.2. The filter would consume and parse the request its own way and the `FacesServlet` would end up getting no request data at all (and therefore not be able to continue the JSF lifecycle "as usual"). Removing the filter alone would also not work as `<t:inputFileUpload>` is internally relying on the semantics/specifics of the MyFaces extensions filter.

Your best bet is really to just remove the filter from the `web.xml` altogether and replace the `<t:inputFileUpload>` by `<h:inputFile>`. It must be bound to a [`javax.servlet.http.Part`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/Part.html) property which offers a.o. `getInputStream()` which you can just continue using the same way as before with `<t:inputFileUpload>`.

```
<h:inputFile value="#{bean.uploadedFile}" />
```

```
private Part uploadedFile;

public void save() {
    String name = uploadedFile.getSubmittedFileName();
    String type = uploadedFile.getContentType();
    long size = uploadedFile.getSize();
    InputStream content = uploadedFile.getInputStream();
    // ...
}
```

The upload maximum and threshold size configuration of the filter can be migrated to `<multipart-config>` entry of the `<servlet>` entry of the `FacesServlet` in `web.xml` like below:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <multipart-config>
        <max-file-size>52428800</max-file-size>
        <file-size-threshold>1048576</file-size-threshold>
    </multipart-config>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

#### See also:

- [How to upload file using JSF 2.2 <h:inputFile>? Where is the saved File?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27677397/how-to-upload-file-using-jsf-2-2-hinputfile-where-is-the-saved-file)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the `facelets.LIBRARIES` is Facelets 1.x specific. During the JSF 1.x era, Facelets was a standalone view technology. Since JSF 2.0, Facelets is embedded in JSF itself and all its context parameters are migrated from `facelets.XXX` to `javax.faces.FACELETS_XXX`. You can find them all in a.o [Overview of all JSF-related web.xml context parameter names and values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17339830/overview-of-all-jsf-related-web-xml-context-parameter-names-and-values). However, you don't need to explicitly register that Tomahawk taglib as well. Just get rid of it.

Comment: So, I was playing around with the filters in my web.xml and after removing ajaxanywhere filter (filter just before extension filter),  t:inputFileUpload tag worked! However, I do need that filter and will have to dig into details as to why ajaxanywhere is consuming it. I would also give a try to JSF h:inputFile. 

Also, for the facelets.LIBRARIES param, I will remove tomahawk taglib. But, I do have custom taglibs and also j4j-facelets taglib. So, I should migrate then to javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES in web.xml. 

Thank you for detailed explanation!!

Comment: Since JSF 2.0, JSF has standard ajax support via `<f:ajax>` tag. You could just drop that almost decade-old AjaxAnywhere thing altogether. I suggest to take a pause and go through a JSF 2.x book/tutorial to do some refreshing. Really a lot of things are done differently (read: better) in JSF 2.x as compared to JSF 1.x.