# JSF 1.2 File upload

Tags: jsf, file-upload, jsf-1.2, tomahawk

I am using tomahawk file uploader functionality in my JSF 1.2 using "t:inputFileUpload" tag.
But it seems tomahawk is not compatible with JSF 1.2, and it works only with JSF 2.0 and above.

Can someone confirm this. Also it would be great if someone gives pointer how to use file upload in JSF 1.2. I dont want to use RichFaces "rich:fileUpload" as it is too much fancy. I just want simple fileInput field and browse button next to it.

Comment: When I use tomahawk in my code, I am not able to see File upload field. Only Submit button is getting dispalyed, and in console I am getting Following warning: com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer getForComponent WARNING: Unable to find component with ID file in view. When I checked the html source code, the tag <t:inputFileUpload> is not getting converted to <input type="file">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *But it seems tomahawk is not compatible with JSF 1.2, and it works only with JSF 2.0 and above.*

This is not true. Tomahawk existed almost as long as JSF itself. It's definitely also available in a JSF 1.2 compatible version.

Apparently you downloaded Tomahawk for JSF 2.0 instead of Tomahawk for JSF 1.2. Tomahawk has admittedly very confusing version numbers. It uses exactly the same 1.1.x version number for both JSF 1.2 and 2.0 versions.

When starting at the [Tomahawk download page](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk/download.html), you should for JSF 1.2 be downloading the version which is listed as follows:

> MyFaces Tomahawk 1.1.14 for JSF 1.2 (zip)         [tomahawk12-1.1.14-bin.zip](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/myfaces/binaries/tomahawk12-1.1.14-bin.zip)

and thus **not** the version which is listed as follows:

> MyFaces Tomahawk 1.1.14 for JSF 2.0 (zip)         tomahawk20-1.1.14-bin.zip

For a more detailed answer as to how to setup it, see also [Uploading files with JSF (1.2)](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/02/uploading-files-with-jsf.html).

Comment: after migration in wildfly 26 I am facing to get null value when upload file we use jsf 1.2 romahawk2 1.1.14, java 8, have any thoughts on this.

Comment: @Suraj, if the answer doesn't work then you have a different problem. The comments section is **not** suitable for asking new questions and posting elaborate answers. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405389/why-is-tinputfileupload-value-mybean-uploadedfile-not-working/10420645?noredirect=1#comment136164262_10420645 This is the third post wherein you pinged me with basically the same cry for help. This is interpreted as disrespectful whining/begging. A next time will greatly reduce my goodwill to answer your newly created question.

Answer (score 0):

Richfaces' file upload is good enough. Its view can be customized by overriding corresponding styles, see the reference for [tag](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_fileUpload.html), Table 6.183 and below.

Answer (score 0):

tomahawk lib has no problem with jsf 1.2,
example for file uploading tag,

```
<h:form id="uploadForm" name="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <table>
                <tr>
                    <h:outputText for="photo" value="Select File: " />
                   <t:inputFileUpload storage="file" size="40" id="photo" value="#{patientsBackingBean.patientPhoto}"/>
                    <h:message for="photo" style="color: red;" />
                </tr>
                </table>
 </h:form>
```

here `patientPhoto` have to declare as `UploadedFile` in backing bean.